# Mango Query + Apache CouchDB 3.x.x - sort array by property from array

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

I have following docs

```
{
  "_id": "products:info",
  "_rev": "3-47add0ce8ecbcb2c4c7dfefae83c02cd",
  "created": "01-26-2022",
  "products": [
    {
      "brand": "MSI",
      "title": "Summit e16",
      "sku": "1000121"
    },
    {
      "brand": "MSI",
      "title": "Summit e13",
      "sku": "1000120"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted to sort `products` array by `sku` property in desc order and get first product sku.

I tried following so far.

**Index**

```
{
 "type": "json",
 "partitioned": true,
 "def": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "products[].sku": "asc"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
   "selector": {
      "products": {
         "$elemMatch": {
            "sku": {
               "$ne": null
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "fields": [
      "_id",
      "products.0.sku"
   ],
   "sort": [
      {
         "products.sku": "desc"
      }
   ]
}
```

Throwing error

```
Error running query. Reason: (no_usable_index) No global index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.
```

Tried following as well

```
{"products.sku": "desc"}
{"products.[].sku": "desc"}
```

Comment: It is not clear whether there are many documents each with an array of `products` or that there is a single document with _id `products:info` - which is it?

Comment: Additionally it *may* be the `no_usable_index` error is occurring because `_id` is not specified in `sort`.

Comment: @RamblinRose Just one document with _id `products:info` this document has `products` array.

Comment: @RamblinRose what do you mean `_id` not specified in sort? I don't need to sort document by `_id`, I want to sort by `document.products[].sku` but as you said I added `_id` to sort object it was throwing same error.

Comment: `sort` sorts *documents* (that satisfy the selector) according to the sort fields.  However there only one document, so there is nothing to sort.  Sort is not array sort.

Answer (score 1):

As commented

> 'sort' sorts documents (that satisfy the selector) according to the sort
> fields. However there only one document, so there is nothing to sort.
> **Sort is not array sort**.

So the desired *outcome cannot be achieved* with a `_find` selector. Since that is so, I will offer a suggestion and an alternative.

First, putting all products into a single file seems like a bad idea - denormalization gone wild? If this is a real world application  do note the `$elemMatch` is an in-memory operation and may result in poor outcomes for a very large product list.

The solution is easily achieved with a view.  Consider this `map` function

```js
function (doc) {
  if(doc._id === "products:info" && doc.products) {    
    doc.products.forEach((product) => { 
      emit(product.sku,{brand: product.brand, title: product.title}); 
    });
  }
}
```

Given the example document from the OP the view index would look like this

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| products:info | 1000120 | {"brand": "MSI", "title": "Summit e13"} |
| products:info | 1000121 | {"brand": "MSI", "title": "Summit e16"} |

There may be other requirements, but this view covers a lot

- Get skus in descending or ascending order; use limit to get first/last/chunks of skus
- Leveraging the `value` field removes the need to load the actual document for specific information
- Reduce = `_count` provides some nice information with regards to (non)null skus for free

In the snippet below the products list is

```json
"products": [{
    "brand": "MSI",
    "title": "Summit e16",
    "sku": "1000121"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Asus",
    "title": "L510",
    "sku": null
  },
  {
    "brand": "MSI",
    "title": "Summit e13",
    "sku": "1000120"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Asus",
    "title": "VivoBook 15 K513",
    "sku": null
  },
  {
    "brand": "MSI",
    "title": "GT72S Dominator Pro",
    "sku": "1000122"
  },
]
```

and the resulting view index looks like this

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| products:info | null | {"brand": "Asus", "title": "L510"} |
| products:info | null | {"brand": "Asus", "title": "VivoBook 15 K513"} |
| products:info | 1000120 | {"brand": "MSI", "title": "Summit e13"} |
| products:info | 1000121 | {"brand": "MSI", "title": "Summit e16"} |
| products:info | 1000122 | {"brand": "MSI", "title": "GT72S Dominator Pro"} |

The default state of the snippet when executing the view solves the OP requirement.

```js
const getDocsToInstall = () => {
  return [{
      "_id": "_design/products:info",
      "views": {
        "skus": {
          "reduce": "_count",
          "map": "function (doc) {\n  if(doc._id === \"products:info\" && doc.products) {\n    doc.products.forEach((product) => { emit(product.sku,{brand: product.brand, title: product.title}); });\n  }\n}"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "products:info",
      "created": "01-26-2022",
      "products": [{
          "brand": "MSI",
          "title": "Summit e16",
          "sku": "1000121"
        },
        {
          "brand": "Asus",
          "title": "L510",
          "sku": null
        },
        {
          "brand": "MSI",
          "title": "Summit e13",
          "sku": "1000120"
        },
        {
          "brand": "Asus",
          "title": "VivoBook 15 K513",
          "sku": null
        },
        {
          "brand": "MSI",
          "title": "GT72S Dominator Pro",
          "sku": "1000122"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let db;
const gel = (id) => document.getElementById(id);

const initDb = async() => {
  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });
  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());
}

async function query(params) {
  console.info(params)
  const results = await db.query("products:info/skus", params);
  gel('results').innerText = JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 2);
}

async function reduce(opt) {
  const params = {
    reduce: true
  }
  if (opt === null) {
    params.startkey = null;
    params.endkey = "0";
  } else if (opt === undefined) {
    params.startkey = "0"
  }
  return query(params);
}

async function view() {
  // sanity
  if (!parseInt(gel('limit').value)) {
    gel('limit').value = 1
  }
  const params = {
    reduce: false,
    include_docs: gel('include_docs').checked,
    limit: parseInt(gel('limit').value),
    descending: gel('descending').checked
  }
  // adjust keys
  if (gel('null_skus').checked) {
    params.startkey = params.descending ? "0" : null;
    params.endkey = params.descending ? null : "0";
  } else if (params.descending) {
    params.endkey = null;
  } else {
    params.startkey = "0";
  }


  return query(params);
}

(async() => {
  await initDb();
  gel('controls').classList.remove('hide');
})();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

.vgap {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<h3>Map/Reduce Alternative</h3>
</pre>
<div id="controls" class="hide">
  <label for="limit">Limit&nbsp;</label><input id="limit" type="number" min="1" value="1" /><br/>
  <input id="descending" type="checkbox" class='vgap' /><label for="descending">&nbsp;Descending</label>
  <input id="include_docs" type="checkbox" /><label for="descending">&nbsp;Include Docs</label>
  <input id="null_skus" type="checkbox" /><label for="null_skus">&nbsp;Null skus</label>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="view()" class="vgap">Execute View</button>
  <hr/>
  <button onclick="reduce('product')">Reduce: Product count</button>
  <button onclick="reduce(null)">Reduce: Null sku count</button>
  <button onclick="reduce()">Reduce: Non-null sku count</button>
  <hr/>
  <pre>
Results
</pre>
  <hr/>
  <pre id="results"></pre>
```

##### Disclaimer

I would normalize products by moving each product into its own document.

Comment: Yes looks like mango query is for limited usecase. I ended up doing something similar to this. I got a view and reduce method to get what I wanted. Thanks for trying this out.